# how to do an atomic copy of 128-bit number in gcc inline x86_64 asm?

Tags: gcc, atomic, inline-assembly

I haven't done assembly since school (eons ago) and have never done any x86, but I have found a pesky bug in old existing code where somebody isn't doing an atomic op where they should be.  The person who wrote the code is long gone and nobody around here knows the answer to my question.  What I need to do is create an atomic copy for 128-bit values.  The code I currently have is as follows:

```
void atomic_copy128(volatile void* dest,volatile const void* source) {
#if PLATFORM_BITS == 64
   #ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER 
      //For IA64 platform using intel compiler
      *((__int64*)source)=__load128((__int64*)dest,((__int64*)source)+1);
   #else 
      //For x86_64 compiled with gcc
      __asm__ __volatile__("lock ; movq  %0,%1"
           : "=r"(*((volatile long *)(source)))
           : "r"(*((volatile long *)(dest)))
           : "memory");
   #endif
#else
   #error "128 bit operations not supported on this platform."
#endif
}
```

This isn't the code that I originally tried, since I've messed with it quite a bit while trying get it to compile and run.  When I make it a totally invalid instruction, it does not compile.  When I run this, it executes until it hits this line and then generates a "Illegal instruction" error message.  I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, "movq" supports at most one memory operand, and its arguments are of 64-bit size anyway, so even if two memory operands were supported, it still wouldn't give you that atomic 128-bit copy you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I assume that "movdqu" also only allows at most one memory operand?  If so, then is there really any way for me to use it for an atomic copy op, since I cannot do it in one instruction, correct?  Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

```
::memset( dst, -1, 16 );
_InterlockedCompareExchange128(source, -1, -1, dst );
```

(but `const` must be deleted)

For other use `cmpxchg16b` instruction